# Checar extensão do arquivo no template - Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma aplicação Django onde no template eu preciso validar a extensão de um arquivo vindo do filefield.

```
<div class="row">
  <p class="anexos">
    {% trans 'Anexos' %}
  </p>
  #if .jpg .png
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{[{ anexo.trajeto }]}"/>
  </div>
  #elif .mp4 .avi
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
    <img class="video-thumbnail" src="{[{ anexo.trajeto }]}"/>
  </div>
  #elif .zip
  <a href="{[{ anexo.trajeto }]}">Arquivo Compactado</a>
  #endif
</div>
```

Como resolvo esse problema?

Comment: Esse `{[{ anexo.trajeto }]}` é assim mesmo, ou seria `{{ anexo.trajeto }}`? Nunca vi essa sintaxe antes, se estiver correto, o que ela faz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [filtro `slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice), ele funciona da mesma forma que o *array slicing* do Python. Ou seja, se você quer a extensão, basta olhar os últimos 4 caracteres do nome do arquivo (assumindo uma extensão de 3 letras, mas pode-se adaptar para outras extensões tipo `.jpeg`).

Exemplo (nota: não testei, tenho pouca experiência com tags de template, não tenho certeza se é possível comparar elementos dessa forma)

```
#if .jpg .png
{% if anexo.trajeto|slice:"-4:" == ".jpg" or
      anexo.trajeto|slice:"-4:" == ".png" %}
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ anexo.trajeto }}"/>
</div>
#elif .mp4 .avi
{% elif anexo.trajeto|slice:"-4:" == ".mp4" or
        anexo.trajeto|slice:"-4:" == ".avi" %}
...
```

Fonte: [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7260472/520779). De todo modo, eu sugeriria fazer isso na *view* em vez do template, se possível (já entregando a extensão do arquivo pro template na forma de uma variável simples).

Answer (score 3):

Além da solução de mgibsonbr, eu preferiria fazer um *template tag* de forma que você possa reutilizar a lógica em outros templates.

**seuprojeto/seuapp/templatetags/extensao.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def extensao(value):
    # retorna a extensao:
    return value[-4:] 

@register.filter()
def class_da_extensao(value):
    # retorna a class dependendo da extensao:
    ext = value[-4:]
    if ext in ['.jpg', '.png']:
        return 'img-thumbnail'
    elif ext in ['.mp4', '.avi']:
        return 'video-thumbnail'
```

**template.html** (neste caso só usei a tag `class_da_extensao`)

```
{% load extensao %}
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
   <img class="{{ arquivo|class_da_extensao }}" src="{[{ anexo.trajeto }]}"/>
</div>
```

**Usando apenas extensão:**

```
{% load extensao %}
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
   {% if arquivo|extensao in ".jpg .png" %}
       <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{[{ anexo.trajeto }]}"/>
   {% endif %}
</div>
```

Você pode saber mais sobre como criar suas *template tags* neste link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: O problema dessa solução é o html. Se ele subir um arquivo de vídeo, pelo código que vc está usando, ele vai definir uma classe de video em um <img>

Comment: @jpklzm apenas repeti o código que você colocou na pergunta, então sua pergunta está com erros.

Comment: Template tags resolve seu problema, basta adaptar para atender da maneira que desejar.

Comment: Sua solução faz sentido para checar o tipo do arquivo, mas como farei a condicional dentro do template?

Por exemplo, como vou dizer que se for .jpg vai sair um <img> e com .zip vai sair um <a href>?

Comment: `{% if arquivo|extensao == '.jpg' %}...{% endif %}`, você deve escolher como usar, pode modificar o templatetag, questão de criatividade. Como eu disse, é uma solução a mais.

Comment: @jpklzm editei a resposta e adicionei novo exemplo